# Eclipse error when using a gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am attempting to use my gradle project in Eclipse but get the following error

```
 Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an unexpected error.
Cannot nest 'iC/src/java' inside 'iC'. To enable the nesting exclude 'src/' from 'iC'
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Cannot nest 'iC/src/java' inside 'iC'. To enable the nesting exclude 'src/' from 'iC']
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:798)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3559)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3519)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.setRawClasspath(JavaProject.java:3575)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SourceFolderUpdater.updateSourceFolders(SourceFolderUpdater.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SourceFolderUpdater.update(SourceFolderUpdater.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeJavaProjectInTransaction(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.access$200(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$4.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:736)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2319)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5736)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5693)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeJavaProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeOpenWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeGradleProjectWithWorkspaceProject(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.access$000(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation$1.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2314)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.synchronizeProjectsWithWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.run(SynchronizeGradleBuildOperation.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I have narrowed the error down to this black of code

```
sourceSets{
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [projectDir]
                ['.gradle','build.gradle','gradle','gradlew','gradlew.bat','bin','branding','compsciBuild','db','html','images','jsp','logs','META-INF','scripts','src','styles','theme','web','WEB-INF','build','.svn','reports'].each{excludes->
                exclude excludes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know have to rewrite that block to allow my junit tests to function correctly.  The error I get if I just include

```
sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs = ["${projectDir}/data"]
```

is the following in my junit log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'autopilot' defined in URL [file:etc/applicationContext-parsing.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.compsci.ic.parser.rr.Autopilot]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [data/autopilotCorpus] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not exist
```

I know I could rewrite the junit tests to be more explicit as to where they are looking for the data folder but that is not an option at this time since some developers are still using ant until we've made the switch.

Thanks in advance.

The folder structure is as follows

```
projectDir/src/java
projectDir/test/src/java
projectDir/data
```

*** **Update** ***

I ended up solving this by following @M.Ricciuti suggestions.  My final working code looks as such

```
sourceSets{
    test {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [projectDir]
            ['.gradle/','build.gradle','gradle/','gradlew','gradlew.bat','bin/','branding/','compsciBuild/','db/','html/','images/','jsp/','logs/','META-INF/','scripts/','src/','styles/','theme/','web/','WEB-INF/','build/','.svn/','reports/', 'test/', '*.*', 'etc/', 'lib/', '.settings/'].each{excludes->
                exclude excludes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you describe briefly your current project directory structure?  (where are java sources and java test sources? do you have a parent directory where test resoures files are located or are these test ressources all in root project directory? ) a simple directory tree with main folder would help.

Comment: ok, I will add that above

Comment: to avoid this "nested source directory" error you need to exclude `src` and `test/src` directories from the `test` *resources* SourceSets :   `test {     
        resources {
            srcDirs = [projectDir]
   ['src/',  'test/' /* other resources filters */].each{excludes->
                exclude excludes
            }
        }` .  And don't forget about the trailing '/' character (you have added 'src' in your exclusions, but you need to write 'src/' )

Comment: that did indeed work, just an oversight on my end for not excluding the test folder.  Thank you

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a correct way to make the test resources available, by configuring the test *SourceSets* "resources" directory.

But there are two small errors in your exclusion rules:

- you need to add `test` directory in the excluded directories list
- you forgot about the ending '/' character ( write  'src/' instead of 'src')